# How to encode a PHP file with base64

Tags: base64

:)

I have one ridiculously silly question and most of you would like to reffer me to Google right away, but that didn't helped me out within the first hour. I suppose I didn't knew how to look for. I'm having a PHP file and I'd like to have it in base64 yet I can't get it to work anyhow.

1) I encoded my PHP script to base64(and included the PHP tags). It'll look as following : JTNDJTNGcGhwJTIwVGhpcyUyMGlzJTIwdGhlJTIwUEhQJTIwY29kZSUyMCUzRiUzRQ==

This kind of base64 won't execute so I added the PHP tags to it although the encoded file already had it. Still didn't worked out. Removed the tags from the base64 and tried again, but still didn't worked. Then I tried adding the PHP tags and inside of them added : 
eval(gzinflate(base64_decode('base64 here')));

Still didn't worked out anyhow. Is anyone here kind enough to tell the kiddo how to run a base64 encoded PHP file properly? 
Would be really appreaciated. :)

Comment: Is `eval()` enabled in Your `phpinfo()`?

Answer (score 5):

A simple code:

```
$source = "JTNDJTNGcGhwJTIwVGhpcyUyMGlzJTIwdGhlJTIwUEhQJTIwY29kZSUyMCUzRiUzRQ==";
$code = base64_decode($source);
eval($code);
```

or even shorter:

```
eval(base64_decode("JTNDJTNGcGhwJTIwVGhpcyUyMGlzJTIwdGhlJTIwUEhQJTIwY29kZSUyMCUzRiUzRQ=="));
```

Do you want to encrypt your code? If so, this is not the right way. Use a accelerator like [this one](http://eaccelerator.net/) or [this one](http://www.php-accelerator.co.uk/). They will crypt your codes and make them even faster!

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to use base_64 to encode your php file then the encoded text need to seat in between the php tags including the base_64 tag.

Example:
If your code is: 
`JTNDJTNGcGhwJTIwVGhpcyUyMGlzJTIwdGhlJTIwUEhQJTIwY29kZSUyMCUzRiUzRQ`

Then your code should look like:

```
<?php eval("?>".base64_decode("JTNDJTNGcGhwJTIwVGhpcyUyMGlzJTIwdGhlJTIwUEhQJTIwY29kZSUyMCUzRiUzRQ")); ?>
```

Basically your basic code will look like this:

```
<?php eval("?>".base64_decode("Code Goes here")); ?>
```

There are more simple tools that can give you this option
Check this out: [PHP Encoder & Decoder with Domain Lock](http://codecanyon.net/item/php-encoder-decoder-with-domain-lock/12693460?ref=artaweb)